# Change CENTER const for CENTER array to loop/iterate?

Tags: arrays, react-native, object, constants

I've got a working snack with a helper function that uses const CENTER.

I'm trying to change the const CENTER to a CENTER array with plenty coords so the helper function can iterate/loop? through all the points.

```
    const { latitude, longitude, speed } = position.coords;
    const center = { latitude: 37.600530, longitude: -122.482629 };  //this is to change
    const { radius, distance } = this.calculateMeasurements(latitude, longitude, center);


    calculateMeasurements = (latitude, longitude, center) => {
    const radius = geolib.isPointInCircle(
      { latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude },
      { latitude: center.latitude, longitude: center.longitude },
      1000
    );
    const distance = geolib.getDistance(
      { latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude },
      { latitude: center.latitude, longitude: center.longitude }
    );
    console.log(radius, distance);
    return { radius, distance };
  }
```

I'd like to put a CENTER array like this one maybe: can it work?

```
    const center = [( id: 1, latitude: 34.3434656, longitude: -56.876456 ),
                    ( id: 2, latitude: 35.3434656, longitude: -57.876456 ),
                    ( id: 3, latitude: 36.3434656, longitude: -58.876456 ),
                    ( id: 4, latitude: 37.3434656, longitude: -59.876456 )];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work well. 
Use `map` for loop your array as below. 
And do not forget to use curly bracket when use object elements in array.

```js
const { latitude, longitude, speed } = position.coords;
const centers = [ // use curly brackets for js objects.
{ id: 1, latitude: 34.3434656, longitude: -56.876456 },
{ id: 2, latitude: 35.3434656, longitude: -57.876456 },
{ id: 3, latitude: 36.3434656, longitude: -58.876456 },
{ id: 4, latitude: 37.3434656, longitude: -59.876456 }];

const { radius, distance } = this.calculateMeasurements(latitude, longitude, center);

const results = centers.map(({id, lati: latitude, longi: longitude) => {
  return this.calculateMeasurements(latitude, longitude, {lati, longi});
});

console.log(`results[0] : ${results[0].radius}, ${results[0].distance}`);

calculateMeasurements = (latitude, longitude, center) => {
  const radius = geolib.isPointInCircle(
  { latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude },
  { latitude: center.latitude, longitude: center.longitude },
  1000);
  const distance = geolib.getDistance(
    { latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude },
    { latitude: center.latitude, longitude: center.longitude }
  );
  console.log(radius, distance);
  return { radius, distance };
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Jeff! It compiles ok in the PC but when I try it in a mobile I get an error, evaluating 't.toString', undefined is not an object.. isDecimal
Maybe it doesn´t have to do with the array.

Comment: @Caquibf I think it is not a problem caused by this code. You need to check error throughdebug mode